# I don't understand how they are initializing current solution. Could someone explain what this does?

Tags: python, initialization, boolean, init, self

I don't understand how a boolean can by multiplied by a length. I'm fairly new to coding

```
def __init__(self, capacity, items):
        self.currentSolution = [False]*len(items)
```

Comment: have you tried it and printed it ?

Comment: It's multiplying a list that contains one bool, it's not multiplying the bool.

Comment: `[False]` isn't a Boolean, it's a list (whose only element happens to be Boolean).

Comment: This is something you may use with care if the items are mutable. This is not the case but if you do something like `a=[[True, False, False]] * 5` and try to write `a[0][1] = False` you may end up with something unexpected...

Answer (score 3):

The notation `[value] * number` builds a list containing `value` at each index, with a length of `number`

Example

```
[False]*2 => [False, False]
[False]*10 => [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply a list by N it's actually creates a new list composed of N original lists.

Let me give you an example. When we'll use the following command:

```
[1, 2, 3] * 2
```

We'll get the following list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

So performing [False]*len(items) will actually create a list with the len of len(items) which every is False.

Another way to do the same thing could be:

```
[False for _ in range(len(items))]
```

Comment: `[False for _ in range(len(items))]` does the same thing just because False is immutable.
The list comprehension evaluates the `False` statement multiple times while [False]*n returns n copies of `False` in a list.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that [False]*n creates a list with 1 False in it, then destroying it and creating new list of size N.

[False for _ in range(len(items))], IMO, creates a lazy generator for N Falses and then creating one list out of it.

Therefor I think that the way I suggested might be faster. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)